# Incorrect Animation Rendering of Fragment transition

Tags: android, eclipse, animation, android-fragments, android-transitions

I am using a fragment inside my layout, I wanted slide in,slide out animations for the fragments.

This is how what my fragment looks like

```
 <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_place"


            android:name="com.mainpackage.FragmentOne"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

and this is My slide in animation xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:valueFrom="-1000dp" android:valueTo="0dp"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:propertyName="translationX"
</set>
```

and this is my Slide Out animation xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/decelerate_quint"
        android:valueFrom="0dp" android:valueTo="1000dp"
        android:valueType="floatType"
        android:propertyName="translationX"
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime" />


</set>
```

However, the transition seems to be very weird. 
It seems as if the First fragment(FragmentOne) is always there. 
When the transition is invoked, FragmentOne is displayed for some time, followed by the slide in animation. 
**There is no slide out animation visible.**

I have read that statically fixing a fragment like in my code is not recommended, but is that the reason why I am getting incorrect animations ?
What should I do to fix the transitions?

This is my switching code:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
         FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();



         if(oldt!=t)
         {  fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
         oldt=t;
         }
         else
         {
             fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.none, R.anim.none);
         }
         fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fr);
         fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use Frame layout as the container and set the fragment programmaticly.

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    tools:context="com.wework.mobile.v2.activities.help.FailRequestFragment">
```

And then in the code

```
final FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        // Replace whatever is in the container view with this
        // fragment, and add the transaction to the back stack so the user
        // can navigate back
        transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
        if (add_to_backstack) transaction.addToBackStack(null);

     if(oldt!=t)
     {  fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
     oldt=t;
     }
     else
     {
         fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.none, R.anim.none);
     }

        // Commit the transaction
        transaction.commit();
```

So yes, you should use FrameLayout instead of the fixed fragment in the layout and put the fragment in the layout programmaticly.